# How do I turn off a Heroku server for maintenance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, server, socket.io

I recently created a chat room server on heroku but discovered some unfortunate errors. I am fairly new to heroku, so I am not quite sure as to how to shut it off temporarily. Any ideas?

Comment: Good question but I think this belongs in [software engineering stack exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). Its where you ask higher level design / best practice questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn on maintenance mode follow these steps:

1. Navigate to your app
2. Go to settings
3. Scroll down and look for a switch with the label maintenance mode
4. Turn on maintenance mode

[image][image]